# ListView transparency not working in android 2.2

Tags: android, listview, layout, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a `ListView` in my **MonoDroid** app with transparent list items.
I implemented transparency using color/transparent as `listView` `listSelector` and semi-transparent color for list items background.
This approach works *perfectly* on any *Android 3.x or 4.x* device:

[image: 4]

But *Android 2.2 and 2.3 devices* *fail* to display this and the list looks like this:

[image: 2]

Could someone help me with this?

1) as I am using `mvvmcross` I have `Mvx.MvxListView` instead of `ListView`
2) i have following style items in `listview` `style`:

```
<item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>  
 <item name="android:listSelector">@color/transparent</item>  
 <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/transparent</item>
```

3) I use custom color from my `values/color.xml`:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Comment: can you share the line where you set the transparency? And also are you using the Android Resource Color or a custom one?

Comment: 1) as I am using mvvmcross I have Mvx.MvxListView instead of ListView 2) i have following style items in listview style:   <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>  <item name="android:listSelector">@color/transparent</item>  <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@color/transparent</item> 3) I use custom color from my values/color.xml: <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used following drawable as a list divider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@color/list_default" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/divider_color" android:left="33dp" />
</layer-list>
```

When I replace android:divider="@drawable/list_divider" with @color/transparent the ugly effect dissapears. Now I should just invent the other way to implement this list divider.

**UPDATE:**

Finally I found the solution for the divider as well, the following construction works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/list_default"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="33dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/divider_color"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Please select this as the answer.